# convert yolov5 model to ONNX and run on c++ interface

Tags: onnx, yolov5

I have yolo model as `yolov5s.yaml` and i have saved my weights file as `best.pt` .
Now want to convert yolo model to ONNX and run on c++ interface .
I have gone through this https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/251 but not able to do .Any help or useful resources will be helpful .
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I could run the example mentioned in https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/251 successfully. My torch version is 1.8.0.

Probably your weights file best.pt has invalid values. Did you ever try to use the weights file in above link to export the module successfully?

BTW: you can find examples in https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/tree/master/samples/c_cxx for usage of ONNXRuntime C++ api to run it.

Comment: in the first link no examples is being seen by me can specify any link or resources that will be helpful for me .
Weight file i.e. best.pt is correct because it is giving predictions correct but wanna run same in onnx inference . Thanks for help any link or your example will be more useful for me .

Answer (score 0):

I tried run the examples provided in the first link successfully, the statements are: git clone github.com/ultralytics/yolov5 # clone repo
cd yolov5
pip install -r requirements.txt # base requirements
pip install coremltools>=4.1 onnx>=1.9.0 scikit-learn==0.19.2 # export requirements python models/export.py --weights yolov5s.pt --img 640 --batch 1 # export at 640x640 with batch size 1

It shows the export was successfully. The weight file in above example is yolov5s.pt. What kind of errors did you get by running these statements with your best.pt file?

Comment: can't we use our weight which is trained on my data using yolov5s model

Comment: I believe we can.